# Masonry Gallery stretching everything horizontally

Tags: jquery, masonry

I am trying to implement a masonry gallery of responsive images. However, the images are all stretched. I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4h855fu3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').masonry({
    "itemSelector": ".item",
    "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
  });
});

$('#loadMore').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var randomWidth = Math.round((Math.random() * (4) + 5) * 100);
    var randomHeight = Math.round((Math.random() * (4) + 5) * 100);
    var element = $('<div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/' + randomWidth + 'x' + randomHeight + '" class="image" width="' + randomWidth + '" height="' + randomHeight + '"><a class="overlay" href="#"><h3 class="title">Some title</h3><div class="description">' + '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div></a></div>');

    $('#container').append(element).masonry('appended', element, true);;
  }

  $('#container').imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
    $('#loadMore').show();
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.grid-sizer {
  width: 20%;
}
.item {
  width: 20%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1224px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .grid-sizer {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .item {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .grid-sizer {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .grid-sizer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
.image:after {
  clear: both;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.overlay .title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.overlay .description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.overlay .description p {
  margin: 20px;
}
.item:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
#loadMore {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#bodycontent {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.0.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div id="bodycontent">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="loadMore" type="button">Load more</button>
```

Hit the "Load more" button as often as desired. It almost works great, except for the images being stretched. How do I get the images in the correct resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that you set explicit width/height but then, through the `.image` class, set a `max-width` on it. This means that the width will be restricted but the height will not follow accordingly since it is hard set.

You should remove the dimensions (*width/height attributes*) from the `img` tags.

This will create a problem that masonry cannot calculate the width/height from the start so you need to call `.masonry('layout')` once the images are loaded (*in your existing `imagesLoaded` handler*)

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').masonry({
    "itemSelector": ".item",
    "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
  });
});

$('#loadMore').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var randomWidth = Math.round((Math.random() * (4) + 5) * 100);
    var randomHeight = Math.round((Math.random() * (4) + 5) * 100);
    var element = $('<div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/' + randomWidth + 'x' + randomHeight + '" class="image"><a class="overlay" href="#"><h3 class="title">Some title</h3><div class="description">' + '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div></a></div>');

    $('#container').append(element).masonry('appended', element, true);;
  }

  $('#container').imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
    $('#loadMore').show();
    $('#container').masonry('layout');
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.grid-sizer {
  width: 20%;
}
.item {
  width: 20%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1224px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .grid-sizer {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .item {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .grid-sizer {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .grid-sizer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
.image:after {
  clear: both;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.overlay .title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.overlay .description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.overlay .description p {
  margin: 20px;
}
.item:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
#loadMore {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#bodycontent {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.0.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div id="bodycontent">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="loadMore" type="button">Load more</button>
```

Comment: For some reason, that layout function didn't work for me before, I guess I used it wrong then.

Comment: @ohyeah it would not work on its own. It works in this version because we have removed the `width` and `height` attributes from the `img` tag.

Comment: I removed the width and height tags as well. I included them before for use with a different framework, but they were no longer needed. Everything works as intended now, thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Image width is controlled by the jquery and is based on the browser width. BUT the height is not. 
Two approaches.

1. Remove height attribute from the img tag.
2. Divide height by 2 in img tag (height="' + randomHeight/2 + ')

Comment: why is dividing the height by 2 a solution ? it would just use a different wrong dimension